# Non-Inverting Single Supply comparator hysteresis is too wide

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier

I am trying to convert an input sine wave to a square wave. The sine wave is centered at 2.5V and has an amplitude of 200mV, with a frequency of 100kHz.

I am looking for a hysteresis of 100mV centered around 2.5V. (ie. 50mV below and 50mV above 2.5V)

I am trying to achieve something like the following , where both waves are centered about 2.5V:

[image]

To do so I looked through [Design with Operational Amplifiers and Analog ICs](http://online.sfsu.edu/sfranco/BookOpamp/OpampsJacket.pdf), and I thought that I could work with a VTC offsetting single-supply inverting Schmitt trigger.

[image]

I then calculated the resistance values according to my parameters.

```
VTH = 2.55V
VTL = 2.45V
VCC = 5V
```

[image]

Where I get:

- `R1 = R2 = 1kΩ`
- `R3 = 1kΩ`
- `R4 = 50kΩ`
- `R5 = 100Ω`

Testing this on proteus:

[image]

yields undesired results:

[image]

I was expecting the hysteresis of 100mV and not 200mV.

On closer inspection, `VTL` is  2.4Vand `VTH` is  2.6V. This can be remedied by increasing R4 while keeping R3 constant. I would like to know why my initial calculations were incorrect.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you arrive at the value for R5? It seems much too high to me...like by 100X.

Comment: Try making R5 << R4.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Indeed that is a big mistake. Updating question immediately

Comment: Well 100 ohms is too low. Try something around 5k\$\Omega\$. Be aware that the output low voltage for an LM339 can be as high as 400mV and is typically 130mV (at room temperature, sinking 4mA).